# Error port 22: Connection refused al conectar por ssh en RedHat

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtualización, red-hat

Monte una máquina virtual en virtualbox Versión 5.2.30 con RedHat 7.5 y estoy tratando de conectarme por ssh desde Windows 10. El servidor responde a ping pero no logro solucionar entrar a la VM por ssh.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando me trato de conectar por ssh me sale esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: podrais cambiar las imagenes por texto?

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]

Comment: tu problema esta relacionada al manejo de aplicaciones en el sistema operativo o configuración de tu red, y no a algo relacionado a los objetivos del sitio (Desarrollo y programación).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dentro de tu máquina virtual utiliza algo como

```
sudo netstat -tlpn | awk '/ssh/{print $4}'
```

O, si no tienes `netstat`

```
sudo lsof -i TCP -s TCP:LISTEN | grep -Po '^ssh.*TCP \K.*(?= \(LISTEN\))'
```

Y si te aparece algo de la forma `*:ssh` en este último comando, entonces es el puerto 22.

Con estos comandos puedes ver en qué puerto está corriendo el servidor `ssh`.

Si no te aparece nada con esos comandos entonces primero revisa si tienes instalado el servidor ssh con `yum list installed` y si no lo tienes, instalalo con `sudo yum install -y openssh-server` y luego inícialo con `sudo service sshd start`.

Si ya lo tienes instalado entonces reinícialo con

```
sudo service sshd restart
```

O

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

Otra opción que podrías aplicar es usar `nmap` fuera de tu máquina virtual, en tu host, para ver en qué puerto está corriendo el servidor `ssh`.

```
nmap -T4 -A <la ip de tu VM>
```

Y si está corriendo en otro puerto, usas `ssh <tu usuario>@<la ip de tu VM> -p <puerto>`

Comment: muchas gracias por tu tiempo segui lo que me indicaste y funciono. Gracias.